# If else regex condition not matching

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the start of the domain using regex but to check if the domain includes the `@`-symbol or not.

So for:

- `test@hotmail.com` I want to match the position after the `@`
- `hotmail.com` I want to match at the start of the line

What I have is:

```
(?(?=[@])(?<=@)|^)
```

I understand that if else conditions work like this

```
(?(?=regex)then|else)
```

1. Do a positive look forward for the `@` symbol: `(?=[@])`
2. If it matches I do a positive look behind from the `@`symbol: `(?<=@)`
3. else/or `|`
4. Match start of line `^`

However for `test@hotmail.com` and `hotmail.com` it always matches at the start of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the following :

```
^(?!.*@)|(?<=@)
```

It matches the start of the string only if there's no `@` in the rest of the string, and the 0-width space after the `@` otherwise.

Explanation :

- the whole pattern is an alternation between "start of the string if it isn't followed by `@`" and "the space after an `@`"
- `^(?!.*@)` matches the start of a string that isn't followed by an `@` anywhere in the string by using a negative lookahead.
- `(?<=@)` matches the space after a `@` using a positive lookbehind

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/qlQFIH/2).

The problem with your if/else is that the predicate doesn't check the whole string but only the next character, so when the first character isn't an `@` it will match the start of the string. Moreover, your "predicate" and your "then" don't go together : the predicate tests that the following character is an `@`, and the then tests that the previous character is. I don't think that if/else hack works well with lookarounds.

Comment: This is a good tool in case you want to visualise your regex pattern https://jex.im/regulex/

Comment: @CodeManiac doesn't seem to work with look-behinds though. There's the top-right panel of regex101 that tries to explain the regex otherwise, but the presentation isn't as good

Comment: yes it was designed a long back with the JS regex flavour and at that time there wasn't lookbehind available for JS. But yeah Regex101 has debugger as well which will give you step by step evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question ans +1 to both OP and the accepted answer. I see @Aaron has accepted answer already, but here is how to get it using `conditionals` as you were asking in the questions (`if/else`) condition

May be not as clean as the accepted answer. I am just presenting a diffent solution

```
/(?(?!.*@)(.*)|(?:@(.*)))/gm
```

Here is the solution on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8kpiq7/1)

Explanation:

```
(?   -- conditonal 
   (?!.*@)(.*)   looks to not to have @ then select the whole string -- having only hotmail.com

   |   OR -- else condition meaning if the string has @
      (?:@(.*))   -- get the string after @ ..meaning it excludes "test@" and captures hotmail.com
```